# Redirect wildcard subdomain without known domain - htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, http-status-code-301

What is the appropriate way to redirect via htaccess when a top level domain name is not known?

My specific situation is this... Our company has a custom content management system that is used on several of our servers. Each server had a subdomain for each of our customers on that server.

i.e.

- customerBob.exampleA.com
- customerLarry.exampleA.com
- customerJudy.exampleB.com
- customerAlice.exampleB.com

We have many servers, each one hosting a group of customers. The subdomains were completely unnecessary, as customers can already access their account from the top level domain. It just makes support more complicated and help files messier.

We would like to eliminate all subdomains and redirect the subdomain to the main domain.

So if one visits: customerBob.exampleA.com/test.php --> they should be directed to --> exampleA.com/test.php.

**I would like to wildcard the top level domain.** All the examples I have seen for htaccess redirects show example.com specified in the destination. Is it possible for me to redirect to the top level domain without knowing what that top level domain might be?

This is the code someone came up with, and it completely fails, I am getting a 500 at this point:

`RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^/.]+)\.(*)\.(*)$ 
RewriteRule (.+)$ "/%1" [L,P]`

I assume this is possible since there are many content management systems in existence where this might be necessaryThank you for your help.

Comment: For any 500 error first thing to check is relevant section of Apache error log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've made a small change to the code you were provided:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^/.]+)\.(.*)\.(.*)$ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%2\.%3/$1 [L,R]
```

For me this is returning `http://exampleA.com/test.php`. I'm explicitly rewriting to `http`. You might want to change this if you use SSL.

Make sure you clear your cache **before** testing this.

Comment: Thank you. That is almost perfect. Except it takes off the .com or .net on the end. Can you modify your answer to use `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%2\.%3/$1 [L,R]` (notice the %3) and then I will accept it?

Comment: Hey @Terry, I've made the edit. I'm glad I could help by pointing you in the right direction :)

Comment: I just looked back over this and can't believe I missed out the `.com` on the URL.... xD lol - must have had a bit of tunnel vision when making changes.